# The TinyMCE editor is not showing when we edit/create body content

Tags: tinymce, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

We have turned on the TinyMCE module and set the Body flavor to html. Unfortunately, though, the editor control does not display when we edit or create posts. Currently, we're working around this using LiveWriter to publish. What do you know about why TinyMCE wouldn't be working?

[image: Where is TinyMCE]

Comment: Probably some javascript errors? Check your console.

Comment: @devqon Nope. The console just shows two common jQuery warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I was using the markdown flavor for the Body Part without having enabled the Markdown module. Here is how I fixed it:

## Option 1: Enable Markdown

Use this option if you want to keep using markdown.

1. Orchard Admin
2. Modules
3. Markdown > Enable

[image]

## Option 2: Using HTML not Markdown

Use this option if you'd like to use HTML instead of markdown.

1. Orchard Admin
2. Content Definition
3. Blog Post > Edit
4. Parts > Body > Body Settings > Flavor > `HTML`

[image]